# how to detect chromebook is in tablet mode or in laptop mode android

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I am supporting my app into Chromebook.

Does anybody know that in android, how to detect that Chromebook is in tablet mode or in laptop mode?

Comment: Hi, for what purpose you need this information?

Comment: Hi, I need to check that if chromebook is in laptop mode than some of ui should show else no need to show in activity